# react-native-calendars jump to a selected month

Tags: react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm using react-native-calendars.
I have a `<Calendar/>` component.

I've read the docs about dozen times, and couldn't find any better prop for changing month than the `current` prop, which initializes the view of the calendar. For example, if I set `current={"2014-01-01"}`, I will see calendar of 2014, 1st of Jan. The problem is I can't re-render this prop.

I also tried to use `key` prop, but it doesn't change date. Ref is not an option either, I've got custom `<CalendarHeader/>`

**package.json**

```
 "react": "17.0.2",
 "react-native": "0.66.4",
 "react-native-calendars": "1.1274.0"
```

**Calendar.tsx**

```
const CalendarScreen = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('2020-01-01');

return (
        <Calendar
          current={current}
          customHeader={CalendarHeaderHandler}
          style={styles.calendar}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCurrent('2021-01-01')}>
            <Text>2021</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
 )};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved this issue by adding both props `key` and `current`

Prop `key` triggers re-rendering

```
  const CalendarScreen = () => {
      const [current, setCurrent] = useState('2020-01-01');

  return(
        <Calendar
          current={current}
          key={current}
          customHeader={CalendarHeaderHandler}
          style={styles.calendar}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCurrent('2021-01-01')}>
            <Text>2021</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
   )};
```

Comment: Is there an explanation for why key is the property that triggers a re-render? Is key from the reac-native side or is it from the library?